# Get pulseaudio current sample rate and bit rate

Tags: pulseaudio

just bought sound blaster X-Fi HD (USB) and i'm trying to understand what is the current output (sample rate and bit rate).

I've configured /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and set there the following values:

default-sample-rate = 96000
default-sample-format = s24le

How do i validate it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pulseaudio settings adhere to the sink they are made for. Hence we are able to read the values we gave with the following command:

```
pacmd list-sinks
```

This will give a rather lengthy list including the following information similar to this

```
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
```

as this was set for my internal card.

Comment: Great thanks a lot!
where can read about how pulseaudio works? (what is sink, source and all of this stuff, relevant files, what is the relationship with ALSA, etc.)

Comment: You may try to figure out things from http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/ or from the nice Wiki maintained by Arch people: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio

Answer (score 6):

You can also look under the hood of ALSA itself, to double check what sample rate your hardware is actually set to.

`less /proc/asound/card0/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params`

(numbers may vary, e.g. card1, and maybe a different playback channel on the card.  xp are playback channels, xc are capture channels).  Not 100% sure if the hw_params file is specific to hda_intel, or if it'll be there with whatever alsa driver you have.

In a typical setup, applications use the default ALSA output, which is actually a hook to send the audio through pulseaudio, which itself outputs to hardware through alsa, using the actual names of the hw device.  (alsa devices are specified with text strings like `hw:0`, or `default`).

Comment: `/proc/asound` doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: @endolith: it does for me on x86-64 Linux 4.20.3-arch1-1-ARCH, on a mobo which has sound hardware so the ALSA modules are loaded.  IDK if Ubuntu might have applied any patches that change something.